# Using Juniper EX3300 as a router

Tags: networking, routing, vlan, juniper, junos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the Juniper EX3300 Switch as a router?](https://serverfault.com/questions/401397/using-the-juniper-ex3300-switch-as-a-router)

So I have a Juniper EX3300 Switch. One of its uplink ports (ge-0/1/0) is connected to my ISP's router. ISP router's port address is xx.xx.xx.109. My switch's IP address is xx.xx.xx.110.

From the switch, I can ping to xx.xx.xx.109 and any other IP in the world. I mean its connected to the Internet.

I connected the port eth0 of a computer (running Ubuntu) to the port ge-0/0/0 of the switch (which in the same VLAN as ge-0/1/0). I configured the port eth0 as follows:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address yy.yy.yy.208
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    gateway xx.xx.xx.110
```

yy.yy.yy.208 is assigned to me by the ISP. So, now I can ping to the switch (xx.xx.xx.110) from this computer. But I can not ping to either xx.xx.xx.109 (ISP router) or any other IP.

I want this computer to be connected to the Internet. What am I doing wrong?

Here are some of the configurations on my switch:

```
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    ge-0/1/0 {
        ether-options {
            no-auto-negotiation;
            link-mode full-duplex;
            speed {
                1g;
            }
        }
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
            }
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    vlan {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.0.1.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 1 {
            family inet {
                address xx.xx.xx.110/30;
            }
        }
    }
}
.
.
.
routing-options {
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0/0 {
            next-hop xx.xx.xx.109;
            retain;
        }
    }
}
vlans {
    Cogent {
        vlan-id 3;
        interface {
            ge-0/1/0.0;
            ge-0/0/0.0;
            ge-0/0/1.0;
            ge-0/0/2.0;
            ge-0/0/3.0;
        }
        l3-interface vlan.1;
    }
    TFLan {
        vlan-id 2;
        interface {
            ge-0/0/5.0;
            ge-0/0/6.0;
            ge-0/0/7.0;
            ge-0/0/8.0;
            ge-0/0/9.0;
            ge-0/0/10.0;
            ge-0/0/11.0;
            ge-0/0/12.0;
            ge-0/0/13.0;
            ge-0/0/14.0;
            ge-0/0/15.0;
            ge-0/0/16.0;
            ge-0/0/17.0;
            ge-0/0/18.0;
            ge-0/0/19.0;
            ge-0/0/20.0;
            ge-0/0/21.0;
            ge-0/0/22.0;
            ge-0/0/23.0;
            ge-0/0/4.0;
        }
        l3-interface vlan.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop reposting your question please. You cannot use the EX3300 as a NAT router, stop trying.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff, look carefully... the problem is not NAT for this particular issue

Comment: There needs to be someone in your organization who understands IP networking. Really, there's no way around this requirement. (The most obvious problem -- how is that computer supposed to reach its gateway since its gateway is outside its subnet? It would need a gateway to reach the gateway!)

Comment: @MikePennington - even if he fixes the glaring subnetting issue, it's still not going to magically NAT

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff, subnet `10.0.1.0/24` is assigned to l3-interface `vlan.0`.  *His Ubuntu machine is on* **`vlan.1`** *(I know this because he said it's on `ge-0/0/0`)*.  He put two different subnets (a /30 and /28) in the same vlan

Comment: He needs to buy a router

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff Its working now, without the need of a router.

Comment: Sure... but you're probably using all public addressing, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want this computer to be connected to the internet.  What am I doing wrong?

**Summary info**

Recalling information from the discussion in [Using the Juniper EX3300 as a router](https://serverfault.com/questions/401397/using-the-juniper-ex3300-switch-as-a-router):

- `ge-0/1/0` is assigned a public /30 address by Cogent.  For sake of illustration, we will call EX3300's address on this subnet `192.0.2.109/30`.  Your default gateway is `192.0.2.110/30`.  From the configuration above, you have assigned `ge-0/1/0` to `vlan.1` using vlan-id 3.
- `ge-0/0/0` is also assigned a public IP address.  For the sake of argument, this subnet is `192.0.2.208/28`.  `ge-0/0/0`'s subnet is different than `ge-0/1/0`.  The interface addressing (and a few other things) need to be fixed.

### List of items to fix

1. You can't assign `192.0.2.208/28` to the Ubuntu server.  .208 is the subnet adddress, and .223 is the broadcast address.  Valid host addresses in this subnet range from `192.0.2.209` to `192.0.2.222` (it doesn't matter that I'm using [RFC 5737 addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737) here, the subnet math works out the same).
2. You need `l3-interface vlan.1` for your /30 link to the Cogent router; however, you also have the Ubuntu machine in that same subnet on a /28. Now that we have established that the Ubuntu server is in a different subnet than `ge-0/1/0`, please follow standard internet engineering practices and *assign a different vlan to that subnet*.  Let's call it `l3 interface vlan.100` with `vlan-id 100` on your EX3300. Assign `192.0.2.209/28` to your `vlan.100` on the EX3300 and use it as the default gateway for this new subnet.
3. Even if you assigned a valid host address to your Ubuntu server (see point 1., above), that server's default gateway *must* be in the same subnet.  Assign `192.0.2.210/28` to the Ubuntu server and make the default gateway `192.0.2.209`.

**Purely informational material**

FYI, We also said that you cannot use [private IP addresses (RFC 1918)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) without [`NAT` (RFC 3022)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3022). I see that you have `10.0.1.1/24` assigned to `vlan.0`.  Anything in 10.0.0.0/8 is [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) space.  If these devices need to access the internet, you will need some form of NAT.

May I suggest:

- [a good book on internet routing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1587052024); it's geared towards Cisco IOS, but the concepts are still very similar.
- [a good book on TCP/IP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131876716)

Best of luck to you in this endeavor.

Comment: I don't need the `10.0.1.1/24` devices to access Internet. OK, I did exactly what u said. I created a new `VLAN (4)` and assigned it `xx.xx.xx.209/28`. I assigned the ubuntu server `xx.xx.xx.210/28` and gateway `xx.xx.xx.209`. Now I can ping the `xx.xx.xx.209` (of course) AND `xx.xx.xx.110` (the address of `VLAN 3`). But I still can't get any further than that

Comment: By the way the Cogent router IP is totally different from my assigned IP range. I dont know how to say it, but only the first part of both of them is same. i.e. they both start with 38. but everything is different after that

Comment: Have you verified that Cogent is pointing the next-hop for their /28 routes to `192.0.2.110`? (you will need to replace my example address w/ the real address).  Also, can you still ping your default gateway to Cogent from the EX3300? (I'm calling the Cogent gw `192.0.2.109/30`)

Comment: Yes I can ping the cogent gateway from my switch. but not from the ubuntu server.

Comment: If Ubuntu can ping `192.0.2.110` and Cogent cannot ping `192.0.2.209`, then it sounds like Cogent hasn't got their /28 pointed at `192.0.2.110`

Comment: I talked to the people at Cogent and he said that I need to create a default route for xx.xx.xx.208/28 VLAN to 192.0.2.110.

Comment: Ok, I can now ping to my xx.xx.xx.209 address (which is my switch) from my home network. but I can't ping to xx.xx.xx.210 (my ubuntu server). does it tell anything?

Comment: Here is a link to the output from traceroute, from my home network to my ubuntu server (xx.xx.xx.210)... It goes till my router (xx.xx.xx.110). [http://pastebin.com/rSVuJcWi](http://pastebin.com/rSVuJcWi)

Comment: Did you put an ACL on your switch?  I cannot ping any of the addresses in question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3865/discussion-between-richard-whitman-and-mike-pennington)